# URLs are not redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS in browser

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have configured the below url in azure application gateway

http://afgabcqtr-adminui-beta.mozcomtest.com/

When I hit the URL in browser it is redirecting to

http://afgabcqtr-adminui-beta.mozcomtest.com/

instead of

https://afgabcqtr-adminui-beta.mozcomtest.com/

The URL is registered in go-daddy

What is the issue in this

The listeners for HTTP and HTTPS are configured in the gateway

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Rule under Rules tab for HTTP Listener which will redirect permanent to HTTPS Listener.
for example:
[image]

[image]

More info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/redirect-http-to-https-portal

Comment: i have created the same. but still not redirecting

Comment: Not sure what you have there but maybe add it to Listener not to external site and also change priority to higher if possible.